# Drawing permanent picture on a static control using CClientDC (Visual C++ 2010 MFC)

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2010

I am fairly new to MFC and windows programming in general and I need to make a sort of interactive graph, where I can click on the different points in the canvas and draw lines between the clicked points
So far I have been able to draw standard shapes in a static picturebox control
However the problem is  that if I drag the part of the dialog box containing by draw figure outside the screen edge, when I bring it back the drawn figure get erased
I need it stay in the static control permanently
After reading few forum questions I see that I need to derive my own static control class from the CStatic class, then write my code in the OnPaint() function for this new static control, but I cannot understand how to do it properly because to use the OnPaint function and WM_PAINT properly I need to use some wizard functions provided in visual studio, but I cannot find any easy tutorials that teach how to do this
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated
This is the code I have so far

```
void Cpaint_using_dcDlg::OnBnClickedDraw()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    COLORREF black = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, black);
     CClientDC Dc(GetDlgItem(IDC_CANVAS));
    // CClientDC Dc(this);
    // Dc.MoveTo(0,0);
    Dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    CPoint point1(0,0);
    point1.x = 0;
    point1.y = 0;
    CPoint point2(0,0);
    point2.x = point1.x + 50;
    point2.y = point1.y + 50;
    Dc.Ellipse(CRect(point1, point2));
}
```

This causes an ellipse to be drawn inside the IDC_CANVAS which is a static picture box control, whenever the command button is pressed

---- UPDATE ----
I was able to create the static control in my diaog box using the following code in the OnInitDialog() function

```
BOOL Cpaint_using_dcDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    CRect rect;
    CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_CANVAS);
    pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    ScreenToClient(&rect); //optional step - see below
    // my_canvas.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_BLACKFRAME|SS_BLACKRECT|SS_ETCHEDFRAME , rect, this, 0x1111);
    my_canvas.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_BLACKFRAME, rect, this, 0x1111);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

The next step is to be able to draw graphics on this static control which do not disappear even when this dialog box is overlapped by another. For this, in the class for my custom static control, I included an OnPaint() function using the class wizard, and included the code to draw an ellipse as shown below:

```
void CMy_Canvas::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    // Do not call CStatic::OnPaint() for painting messages
    CPen pen;
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    // CPoint curPos;
    // GetCursorPos(&curPos);
    CPoint point1(0,0);
    point1.x = 0;
    point1.y = 0;
    CPoint point2(0,0);
    point2.x = point1.x + 50;
    point2.y = point1.y + 50;
    dc.Ellipse(CRect(point1, point2));
}
```

However now it draws the ellipse, but the outline for the static control generated using `my_canvas.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_BLACKFRAME, rect, this, 0x1111);` disappears. Why is that happening and how can I avoid it? Also, what I really need to do is make this graph interactive, so that I can change the structure of the curve that I will display on this control using mouse clicks. Which WM_ message is the appropriate one for doing this? I am assuming it should be `WM_LBUTTONUP` or `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` but I am not sure. Also, suppose I need to draw a line between two points i click on the canvas. Where should I put the code that draws this line? Should it go in the OnPaint() function or in the mouse event handler function?

Comment: Did you derive an own class from CStatic as you read in forum questions? If you do so, please create the class with MFC class wizzard, that makes things easier when adding the OnPaint handler.

Comment: I haven't quite figured out how to use the class Wizard to derive classes yet, and frankly upto this point I am not even sure if this is exactly what I need to do; for eg, lets say I derive a class from CStatic called CStatic_my and it's object is supposed to represent my custom static control; How exactly would I place it on my dialog box? Does it appear as an icon in the toolbox? Or do I have to create it myself inside OnInitDialog(), in which case I will probably have to specify it's coordinates as well, which I am not sure how to do

Comment: Class wizzard: right click on project, then Class Wizzard, then Add Class (MFC Class), then base class=CStatic. You can put a static control into the dialog using the dialog editor (and add a variable for the control/subclass it), but you can also create the control dynamically yourself. Using the dialog editor is the easier way.

Comment: "You can put a static control into the dialog using the dialog editor (and add a variable for the control/subclass it)". I apologize if this is very beginner question but I am not sure what that meant. Did you mean I can include my custom static control through the form designer? Also, the class wizard created a sort of template with empty constructor and other functions. Do I need to include any code within these functions, to start using my derived class? Or can I just start creating objects of this class and use the members provided by CStatic?

Comment: I am assuming I need to start by creating an object of the custom static control inside the class representing my dialogue box, but I am not sure how I can place it where I want it

Comment: In the ressource editor you can't directly add your custom static control, but you can add a CStatic. You can place the control where you want and make it the size you want. Then you use Class Wizzard to add a control variable for your control to your dialog, you will need to make it a CMyStatic instead of a CStatic.

Comment: Here is a walkthrough: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480/Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check out your link. In the meantime please have a look at the update I made to my question

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create the custom static control in OnInitDialog. Use the static control (IDC_CANVAS) that you created in the visual designer. In that designer right-click on the control and add a control member variable. Change that control member variable type from CStatic to CMyCanvas. Now your custom control class should receive the OnPaint call.

Comment: Wow it works. Thanks a lot. I have commented out the code that I used to create the control in the `OnInitDialog()` function. It replaces the `CStatic` I had placed using the forms designer by my `CMy_Static` control. I know this because I have placed code to draw an ellipse in the `OnPaint()` of `CMY_Static`. However the borders I had defined for the `CStatic` control from the forms designer completely disappear. Where and how do I specify the appearance for `CMy_Static`?